# editing .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I've made an application using CodeIgniter, and I tried to use the apache mod_rewrite rules as listed on the [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The problem is that I have this app in a folder `abc/`, but when I type `mysite/abc/something` (which should point to `mysite/abc/index.php/something`) I get redirected to `mysite/index.php/something`.

What changes should I make to the `.htaccess` file to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a relative path in the substitution:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond $1 !(index\.php|^images|^robots\.txt)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L,NS]
```

Comment: did you forget the `^` or is it like that? moreover what does [L,NS] do?

Comment: I removed the initial ^ on the RewriteCond so that it will ignore any index.php in your site, not just /index.php (^index.php will NOT match /abc/index.php; it being in a .htaccess in a subdirectory does not make the paths relative to that subdirectory).  The ^ and $ in the rule were irrelevant.

Comment: The NS suppresses the rule on subrequests.  When the rule triggers, a subrequest is generated with index.php/whatever as the URL; the NS stops the rule from looking at the subrequest.  The RewriteCond's index.php check should also prevent that from being rewritten, so it's kinda belt-and-suspenders.